# How can I override configurations from the built-in ftplugins?

Tags: neovim, ftplugin

I would like to set `commentstring` for C files like so:

```
autocmd FileType c setlocal commentstring=//\ %s
```

But when I open a C file, I notice that setting has been overridden. I believe this line from `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/c.vim` is to blame:

```
setlocal commentstring& define& include&
```

Is there a way I can modify my `init.vim` to make my setting take precedence? If not, what's the most natural place to put such a setting? (And as a side question, is this behavior intended, or possibly a bug in Neovim?)

Comment: try using `set` instead of `setlocal`

Comment: Trying it just now, that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: is filetype enabled in init.vim

Comment: `set filetype` shows `filetype=c` in C files, and putting `set filetype=on` in my `init.vim` does not change the behavior. Out of curiosity, are you able to repro the issue? I can confirm that it repros with no plugins and an empty init.vim for me.

Comment: it is working on my side try enabling plugin too

Comment: what version of neovim you are using?

Comment: That did it! Thank you! (Neovim 0.5) When I put `filetype plugin on` before (not after) the `autocmd` in my `init.vim`, that makes my `autocmd` take precedence like I wanted. (Presumably because it sets the built-in autocommands first?) If you post this as an answer, I'd be very happy to give you the bounty for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling filetype and plugin in `init.vim`

```
filetype plugin indent on
...
...
...
autocmd FileType c setlocal commentstring=//\ %s
```

Note: The order is mandatory or else it would not work because user defined configs will be overwritten by defaults configs as when we enable filetype and plugin it tries to load defaults configs.